# 0.000039 Output To 4 × 10^(-5)

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 input box in my html file to devise two numbers, if the output (result) is equal to 0.000039 how to make it 4 × 10^(-5) (not 4e-4)?

Comment: Please post the JavaScript code that you have.

Comment: You should consider adding more information and maybe some code. Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const output = '4e-4';
const parts = output.split('e-');
const result = `${parts[0]}x10^(-${parseInt(parts[1])+1})`;
console.log( result )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>

    <input id="nb1" type="tel">
    <p></p>
    <input id="nb2" type="tel">
    <p></p>
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="=" onclick="myFun();"/>
    <p></p>
    <p id="result"></p>

    <script>

 function myFun() {

 var nb1 = document.getElementById("nb1").value;
 var nb2 = document.getElementById("nb2").value;
 var x = nb1 / nb2;

 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= x;
 }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```